# How to get respond from promise in JSON parse?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to get response from API call in the JSON parse but do not see a way to get it.

I managed to get respond from promise but it's not usable because i need JSON parse respond (JSON.stringlify worked but also not usable) .

```
let Admins = scope.api.getChatAdministrators(scope.message._chat._id)
        console.log(Admins);
        Admins.then(function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        })  // Why this work?(I get this respond from it)
```

```
Respond:
[ ChatMember {
    _user:
     User {
       _id: ID,
       _firstName: 'AdminBot',
       _lastName: null,
       _username: 'Bot' },
    _status: 'administrator' },
  ChatMember {
    _user:
     User {
       _id: ID,
       _firstName: 'Creator',
       _lastName: null,
       _username: 'Creator' },
    _status: 'creator' } ]
```

```
let Admins = scope.api.getChatAdministrators(scope.message._chat._id)
        console.log(Admins);
        Admins.then(function(result) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(result));
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log('API Call error:', err.message);
        });
```

Tried this to get JSON parse output but i got response "API Call error: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1"

Answer (score 0):

This will look weird but this will do.

```
const temp = JSON.stringify(result)
const parsedResult = JSON.parse(temp)
```

FYI. you can only parse a JSON object in string format.

Comment: let Admins = scope.api.getChatAdministrators(scope.message._chat._id)
        console.log(Admins);
        Admins.then(function(result) {
        console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result)));
        }).catch((err) => {
          console.log('API Call error:', err.message);
        });

I tried also your method and i got the same respond so im probably on good way.. but i have problem to put those values from respond in the statement.. all other calls do not have [    ] at the start.. :(

Comment: do you have some git or code pen for this so that i can have a look? @RasmonT

Comment: I am sure the data it's returning isn't in JSON like format. This response looks something like typescript. @RasmonT

Comment: Check this please,

Comment: Couldn't figure out much. But, here's some few things I saw. There's a pending promise in there. I am guessing there must be a backend part for this code. And, you might have directly sent the `pending commit` with out using a await or resolving it. @RasmonT

Comment: I think that's because of  console.log(Admins); which is the promise.. i tried to removed it and is it not appearing upside anymore.. the result respond is still last but im not sure if its correct respond to use the data from it into statements because i have troubles with that :/ , and how i can do `pending commit` you mentioned ? Any ideas for it.. Thanks!

Comment: My bad, it was kind of a long text to figure out. Nope, `then` handles it well.

Comment: The problem is that i do not seem to respond seems correct... Have problem to add values into statement to compare if user has the admin id or not.. :/ Now confused what can exactly be issue and i feel that those [] are different format than JSON as you told...

Comment: This is somekind of chat bot api. Can you share the api doc you are using and a rough idea that you are trying to implement. I guess I can set up a project at my end and find a solution. @RasmonT

Comment: https://github.com/Naltox/telegram-node-bot    
I just want to use respond from api (getadmins) to compare if the has the admin id or not.. If not it will do action that already working (Solved this by primitive way that i putted admin ids into statement) But i want bot itself to recognize who is admin and who does not...